Dependency injection in Blazor does not work while switching page
I have a class
public class SessionState 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
}

And in every page I have injected the class with @inject SessionState state.
I want to fill state.id while the user login, I wrote this code:
state.id = some value;
state.verified = true;
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("home");

And I have this code in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<SessionState>();

Now when the web site navigates to Home, I have no value in state.id.
I also used this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SessionState>();

but the problem is when user 1 logs in I have state.id = 1, after user1 user2 logs in and I have state.id = 2
How can I have state.id unique for every user that logs in, and I need it in all of my Blazor pages.
state.id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["iduser"].ToString());
state.verified = true;
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("home");


Once user logged in, add require details to the local storage. And use those information to show user info, tokens etc. Using singleton doesn't make sense here.

Singleton services share the same instance and thus the same data across all sessions and users. When you logs in a new user in a new page , the old user is replaced and state.id changes too. Session.storage is a good choice and you could consider CascadingValue to pass the value.

@FengzhiZhou i didnt use the singleton, i used scoped. but my problem with scoped is that when the program goes to new page state.id value has been reset and is not transfered to the new page

@DivyangDesai do you have any link to help me with local storage ? i don't know what is it.

The official document offers the session and local storage way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server#server-side-storage-server
1.Works when pre-render is disabled
In your App.razor
<HeadOutlet @rendermode=@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)) />
<Routes @rendermode=@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)) />

In your component
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
...
await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("count", currentCount);
...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("count");
    currentCount = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
}

2.Works when per-render is enabled
In your App.razor
<HeadOutlet @rendermode=@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: true)) />
<Routes @rendermode=@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: true)) />

In your component
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
...
await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("count", currentCount);
...
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("count");
        currentCount = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}



Every new tab separates from the others and have their own storage


Other components get the value too.
The Asp.net core Identity works on static SSR rendering and after my test it still won't work whether disable/enable the prerender, so you might need to customize your login logic. Some relating discussions for you to refer to : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51476
